Old SFTP Issue: paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable host key)
Error:

paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable host key)

Paramiko Version: 2.8.1 [cannot update unfortunately]
Debug Logs:
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x28252fd0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.8.1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-AWS_SFTP_1.1
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client AWS_SFTP_1.1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['ecdh-nistp384-kyber-768r3-sha384-d00@openquantumsafe.org', 'x25519-kyber-512r3-sha256-d00@amazon.com', 'ecdh-nistp256-kyber-512r3-sha256-d00@openquantumsafe.org', 'ecdh-nistp521-kyber-1024r3-sha512-d00@openquantumsafe.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256'] server key:['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256'] client encrypt:['aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes192-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes192-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com'] server mac:['hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Exception: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable host key)

Obtaining private key using:
pkey = Ed25519Key.from_private_key(io.StringIO(private_key_ascii))

since
pkey = RSAKey.from_private_key(io.StringIO(private_key_ascii))

was not working.

Well, you will have to upgrade.
Your server has only rsa-sha2 hostkeys:
server key:['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256'] 

Paramiko supports those since 2.9.0 only:
https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.9.0
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1643
